# Parsing JSON in a SAS field

Tags: json, sas

Does SAS have a simple way to parse JSON data within a SAS column yet?  I know it can be done with the json object in `proc ds2` but that's an awful approach.  I'm looking for something that makes it trivial like the JSON libname option but without having to dump everything to a temporary file first.

Comment: Have you tried PROC JSON?

Comment: @PythonRSAS I thought `proc json` was to create JSON formatted data, not parse it?

Comment: Oops sorry. Misread the question.

Comment: Proc groovy can parse json: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Parse-json-file-with-Proc-Groovy/td-p/187484

Comment: but with proc groovy you can't read datasets. Proc lua can read datasets but need third party library

Comment: No, not yet. Are the stored JSON snippets trivially structured?  Can you make the question more specific with example snippets and how data items within are to be specified? Is parsed data output across the row, across several rows, or a tall group of pathname:value pairs? Is the JSON consistent across all the rows? If not, you might scan the data set twice. 1st to first understand the paths available across all the rows and a 2nd time to extract the data. Do you have a priori specific 'path-to-property' designations for the data values you want to parse out for the task at hand?

Comment: @Richard Thanks, I figured as much.  Yes it's pretty trivial JSON and I've simply parsed it using nested `scan()` functions for the time being but it just seems like parsing JSON is one of those common tasks that should have a more elegant solution by now.

Answer (score 2):

There is json engine in `libname` statement(read [here](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n1jfdetszx99ban1rl4zll6tej7j.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)). 
But for a start, you need to change input dataset with condition that it is one json:

Have dataset:

```
data have;
length str $ 500;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":1,""string"":""teststring1""}}";
output;    
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":2,""string"":""teststring2""}}";
output;    
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":3,""string"":""teststring3""}}";  
output;    
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":4,""string"":""teststring4""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":5,""string"":""teststring5""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":6,""string"":""teststring6""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":7,""string"":""teststring7""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":8,""string"":""teststring8""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":9,""string"":""teststring9""}}";
output;
str="{""method"":""Get"",""parameters"":{""int"":10,""string"":""teststring10""}}";
output;
run;
```

> ```
> +==================================================================+
> |                               str                                |
> +==================================================================+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":1,"string":"teststring1"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":2,"string":"teststring2"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":3,"string":"teststring3"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":4,"string":"teststring4"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":5,"string":"teststring5"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":6,"string":"teststring6"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":7,"string":"teststring7"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":8,"string":"teststring8"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":9,"string":"teststring9"}}   |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":10,"string":"teststring10"}} |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Formatted dataset:

```
data have_formatted;
   set have nobs=n;
   if _N_=1 then do;
      str = "[" || strip(str) || ",";
   end;
   else do;
      if _N_ < n then do;
         str = strip(str) || ",";
      end;
      else if _N_ = n then do;
         str = strip(str) || "]";
      end;
   end;
run;
```

> ```
> +===================================================================+
> |                                str                                |
> +===================================================================+
> | [{"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":1,"string":"teststring1"}},  |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":2,"string":"teststring2"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":3,"string":"teststring3"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":4,"string":"teststring4"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":5,"string":"teststring5"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":6,"string":"teststring6"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":7,"string":"teststring7"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":8,"string":"teststring8"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":9,"string":"teststring9"}},   |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | {"method":"Get","parameters":{"int":10,"string":"teststring10"}}] |
> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Parse using libname json:

```
filename res temp;

data save;
   file res;
   set have_formatted;
   put str;
run;

libname test json fileref=res;
filename res clear;
```

Result:

```
+---+------------+--------+---+--------------+
| P |     P1     |   P2   | V |    Value     |
+---+------------+--------+---+--------------+
| 1 | method     |        | 1 | Get          |
| 1 | parameters |        | 0 |              |
| 2 | parameters | int    | 1 | 1            |
| 2 | parameters | string | 1 | teststring1  |
| 1 | method     |        | 1 | Get          |
| 1 | parameters |        | 0 |              |
| 2 | parameters | int    | 1 | 2            |
| 2 | parameters | string | 1 | teststring2  |
| 1 | method     |        | 1 | Get          |
| 1 | parameters |        | 0 |              |
| 2 | parameters | int    | 1 | 3            |
| 2 | parameters | string | 1 | teststring3  |
| 1 | method     |        | 1 | Get          |
| 1 | parameters |        | 0 |              |
| . | ...        | ...    | . | ...          |
| 2 | parameters | string | 1 | teststring10 |
+---+------------+--------+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks - but the question is asking for a method that specifically avoids the JSON libname and writing to a file first.